# How to Properly Use FunctionTransformer in a Pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to train a support vector machine on sentence embeddings I created with universal sentence encoder. I use FunctionTransformer inside of a pipeline to fit my model, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

**Code**

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

tos = pd.DataFrame({
    "Character" : ["KIRK", "SPOCK"],
    "Lines" : ["Shall we pick some flowers, Doctor?","Check the circuit."]
})
X = pd.DataFrame(tos["Lines"], columns = ["Lines"])
Y = tos["Character"]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,Y)
embed = hub.Module("/content/module/")
pipe = make_pipeline(
    make_column_transformer(
        (FunctionTransformer(embed), "Lines")
    ),
    SVC()
)
pipe.fit(x_train,y_train);
```

I noticted that the documentation for FunctionTransformer mentions that

> If a lambda is used as the function, then the resulting transformer
> will not be pickleable.

But this does not seem to be the issue, as I did not define this function to be a lambda.

**Full Traceback**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    821             try:
--> 822                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    823             except queue.Empty:

21 frames

/usr/lib/python3.7/queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    166                 if not self._qsize():
--> 167                     raise Empty
    168             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-69-a981c354b190> in <module>()
----> 1 pipe.fit(x_train,y_train)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    388         """
    389         fit_params_steps = self._check_fit_params(**fit_params)
--> 390         Xt = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    391         with _print_elapsed_time("Pipeline", self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):
    392             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params_steps)
    353                 message_clsname="Pipeline",
    354                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 355                 **fit_params_steps[name],
    356             )
    357             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    347 
    348     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 349         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    350 
    351     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    891     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    892         if hasattr(transformer, "fit_transform"):
--> 893             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    894         else:
    895             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    673         self._validate_remainder(X)
    674 
--> 675         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)
    676 
    677         if not result:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted, column_as_strings)
    613                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)),
    614                 )
--> 615                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(transformers, 1)
    616             )
    617         except ValueError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1041             # remaining jobs.
   1042             self._iterating = False
-> 1043             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1044                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1045 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/joblib/parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    831                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    832 
--> 833                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    834                 if len(islice) == 0:
    835                     return False

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/compose/_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    613                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)),
    614                 )
--> 615                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(transformers, 1)
    616             )
    617         except ValueError as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     84     new_object_params = estimator.get_params(deep=False)
     85     for name, param in new_object_params.items():
---> 86         new_object_params[name] = clone(param, safe=False)
     87     new_object = klass(**new_object_params)
     88     params_set = new_object.get_params(deep=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py in clone(estimator, safe)
     65     elif not hasattr(estimator, "get_params") or isinstance(estimator, type):
     66         if not safe:
---> 67             return copy.deepcopy(estimator)
     68         else:
     69             if isinstance(estimator, type):

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    178                     y = x
    179                 else:
--> 180                     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    181 
    182     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    279     if state is not None:
    280         if deep:
--> 281             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    282         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    283             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    148     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    149     if copier:
--> 150         y = copier(x, memo)
    151     else:
    152         try:

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    239     memo[id(x)] = y
    240     for key, value in x.items():
--> 241         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    242     return y
    243 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    178                     y = x
    179                 else:
--> 180                     y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
    181 
    182     # If is its own copy, don't memoize.

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in _reconstruct(x, memo, func, args, state, listiter, dictiter, deepcopy)
    279     if state is not None:
    280         if deep:
--> 281             state = deepcopy(state, memo)
    282         if hasattr(y, '__setstate__'):
    283             y.__setstate__(state)

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    148     copier = _deepcopy_dispatch.get(cls)
    149     if copier:
--> 150         y = copier(x, memo)
    151     else:
    152         try:

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in _deepcopy_dict(x, memo, deepcopy)
    239     memo[id(x)] = y
    240     for key, value in x.items():
--> 241         y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
    242     return y
    243 d[dict] = _deepcopy_dict

/usr/lib/python3.7/copy.py in deepcopy(x, memo, _nil)
    167                     reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce_ex__", None)
    168                     if reductor:
--> 169                         rv = reductor(4)
    170                     else:
    171                         reductor = getattr(x, "__reduce__", None)

TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the instance of `FunctionTransformer` directly in pipeline rather than wrapping it inside a `ColumnTransformer`.

I have not checked the code as I dont have tensorflow_hub installed in my machine. So excuse me if this does not work out for you.

```
pipe = make_pipeline(        
    FunctionTransformer(embed, kw_args={"kw_arg_nm":kw_arg_value}), 
    # Provision someway to pass "Lines" through kw_args.       
    SVC()
)
pipe.fit(x_train,y_train);
```